# Inconsistent backdrop blur in CSS

Tags: html, css

The blur doesn't apply when the dialog's edge is close to a text. I've also tried using dialog element but the problem still persisits.

Here's the image with the code below it:

[image: Here's the image with the code below it]

```css
form {
  display: grid;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-template: auto / 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - (80vh / 2));
  left: calc(50% - (350px / 2));
  width: 350px;
  height: 80vh;
}

.mask {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.637);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
}
```

```html
<h1 style="text-align: center;font-size: 60px;margin-top: 0px;">This is an example text</h1>
<div class="mask"></div>
<form method="POST" action>
  <h1>Add Book</h1>
  <p>
    <label for="book_title">Title</label>
    <input type="text" id="book_title" name="title" required />

    <button type="submit">Add Book</button>
</form>
```

I've tried using dialog element but the problem still persists. Changing this line in form styling solves the problem but I still don't know why it's caused "left: calc(50% - (337px / 2));"

Comment: Which browser are you seeing this issue in? I can't seem to reproduce it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in Chrome, Brave and Firefox browsers. Were you using Safari by any chance?

Comment: I am using chrome on xubuntu which is in a vm. My host OS is windows

Comment: I am using Windows OS and can't reproduce it either.

Comment: You may wish to [edit] your question to include more detail on what exactly "ugly" means to you. One person's ugly in another person's beautiful.

Comment: I cannot reproduce as well. Using Chrome + mac OS Ventura.

Comment: I'll try to reproduce it on windows

Comment: I tried reproducing it on windows can't reproduce but it shows up on linux.